# Default font on a javascript plugin for wordpress

Tags: javascript, css

So I feel as if im getting close to fixing this. Please keep in mine im beyond a rookie but love to learn. Im self taught on CSS, HTML, PHP not very good but I understand the basics.

Running a JS plugin on wordpress - when clicking add text it was arial by default ive changed every 'arial' to the default font that i want..... now when I click add text it adds text with a (im asuming default) font but with the name of the fone im trying to make default. Soon as i click on my fonts name it works as if I need to click it for it to load into the JS code or something...

What can I add to make it load so it can be ran as default?

http://www.signflow.ca/new/design-your-own/?product_id=562&color=FFFFFF

Comment: Normally fonts are loaded with CSS, not JS. You can always override font family with CSS.

Comment: yes but even if the font is only added when you click a button thats js? ive changed every single css file to my font name it doesnt change it. ive tried.

Comment: after adding the font there is options to change it to whatever the customer wants - there is only one option (my custom font) and when I chose it it changed fine ... plus after I chose it the first time then when I click add text it works as it should

Comment: thats why it seems as if it needs to be loaded first before I hit the add text button somehow through java

Comment: Please provide related codes in your question. Plus, Java & JavaScript are not related.